# Did abu hanifah say aqeeqah is an innovation?

Tags: fiqh, reference-request, hanafi, madhhab, aqeeqah

I spent 30 minutes looking for evidences for a statement i heard. The statement is :

> Abu Hanifa said aqeeqah *(sunnah of sacrificing animals to withdraw new born as mortgage from Allah)* is an innovation.

Can only find one engineer ali mirza saying abu hanifah believed that.

Can someone please quote references. If its true?

Ps: the person said abu hanifah believed prayer for rain is innovation and aqeeqah is innovation. Found proof for abu hanifah saying prayer for rain is innovation.

Answer (score 1):

Such a thing is attributed to Abu Hanifa by various scholars. However it is not authentic or is a misunderstanding of what he meant. He considered it to have been abrogated (and hence only nafl or sunnah ghayr mu'akkadah) reasoning from the hadith:

> نسخت الزكاة كل صدقة في القرآن , ونسخ غسل الجنابة كل غسل , ونسخ صوم رمضان كل صوم , ونسخ الأضحى كل ذبح
>
> Zakat abrogated every alms (made obligatory) in the Quran, and the bath for Janabah abrogated every other bath, and fasting in Ramadan abrogated every other fast, and Udhiyah abrogated every other sacrifice
>
> <sup>— [Sunan al-Kubra Bayhaqi](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/21648)</sup>

**Reference:**

> ونقل صاحب (التوضيح) عن أبي حنيفة والكوفيين: أنها بدعة وكذلك قال بعضهم في شرحه والذي نقل عنه أنها بدعة أبو حنيفة. قلت: هذا افتراء فلا يجوز نسبته إلى أبي حنيفة
>
> <sup>— [Umdat al-Qaari](https://shamela.ws/book/5756/6283#p1)</sup>